# My Codeigniter session keeps on destroying after 10-15 min

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, continuous-integration

Here is my code, It was working fine but suddenly starts destroying since 10-15 days, Didn't change any thing before that but after i faced this problem changed few things

Modified `user_agent` column's data type from varchar to mediumtext

Modified `sess_cookie_name` (removed `_` in between the words)

Changed `sess_time_to_update` to 7200

But, still facing this issue. we are using old version(2.1.2)

Here is my code,

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'mysessionname';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 7200;
```

Comment: Did you tried $config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE; ??

Comment: can you point out what you mean by "suddenly starts destroying"?

Comment: @JensBaitinger Few min(approx 15) after logged in it's getting logged out if I keep my pages in idle.

Comment: @Neeraj Singh No, I never tried that.

Comment: @NeerajSingh I did the change as you mentioned but still am getting logged out even I am using the pages continuously.  can you please help me?

Comment: If you are using version 2.2 or older then you have to update your session library because old version has session_update issue and its bugy for random ajax post and keep getting destroyed.  Replace your system/libraries/Session.php file with the one found here (CI’s git): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/b211adee89f5fd2192051e9c0826146bd150f469/system/libraries/Session.php